# How to make On hover the particular div should hide and one more div should display in angular?

Tags: angularjs, css

Here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/awkacLrj/

The issue initially the **class="vote-card-hov"**  should be display:none.
When i hover on "VOTE" **class="votepop"** Then the whole  **class="vote-card-hov"** should be display:block instead of the  **class="vote-card"**.

for ex: https://jsfiddle.net/0s2fy0h5/1/

Here I tried with same method using CSS

```
 all-voting-box .vote-card:hover .vote-card-hov
 {
  display:block;
  border:4px solid;
 }
```

But its not working. help me out in this, Either in angular or CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with angular templates, by using `ng-mouseover`, `ng-mouseleave` and `ng-show`:

```
<span class="votepop" 
      ng-mouseover="hoverActive = true" 
      ng-mouseleave="hoverActive = false">VOTE</span>
```

Then:

```
<div ng-show="hoverActive">
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eby1Luhq/2/)

However, I recommend using an `ng-click` toggle instead of `mouseover`, since there is no mouse on mobile devices.

Comment: @manojistack yes I can see - there is an issue with flickering. You'll need to `position:absolute;` the element that show/hides to avoid this (with `position:relative;` set on it's parent element).

Comment: Even after using position its flickering, Can u help me in same fiddle. ill make yous answer up now. :)

Comment: @manojistack  For this specific instance, you'd be better off using an `ng-click` toggle instead, or maybe `ng-blur` and `ng-focus` depending on what you want exactly. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bj77kn76/3/   

Presumably you'll have an `ng-repeat` to iterate over each item. You could use an index to only open a specific item's popup.

Answer (score 0):

There were two issues:
`.` was missing
+ should be used to select sibling

```
.all-voting-box .vote-card:hover + .vote-card-hov
 {
  display:block;
  border:4px solid;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/amitfts/awkacLrj/1/